# create subdomain in AWS Route 53 and configure on WIX to route the sub domain requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53, velo

I have my domain `example.com` registered and managed on WIX. I want to create a subdomain `staging.example.com` and point it to AWS elastic bean stack application.
I created a public hosted zone Route 53 in `staging.example.com` and created an Alias record to map to the Load balancer.
[image]

**How can I map the subdomain from Route 53 to the WIX DNS record?**

[image]

Comment: Does Wix allow you to add NS record for staging.example.com?

Comment: Hi Dusan,
no, it seems Wix will not allow do edit the NS records.

Comment: You don't need to edit existing NS records for your domain, you would need to add (new) NS records for the subdomain.

Comment: I don't see any option to add the new NS records in the WIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation from WIX is not supporting the NS records modifications.

**Currently, it's not possible to change name servers (edit NS records) for a Wix domain.**

https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-changing-name-server-ns-records-for-a-wix-domain.

The only workaround is to Transferring Your Wix Domain Away from Wix
https://support.wix.com/en/article/transferring-your-wix-domain-away-from-wix-2477749